# StatsModels in Python: What is measured on the horizontal axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, statsmodels

I run the following Python code to generate the attached figure of Kernel density with the horizontal axis from `0` to `500`. Given that the code generates 100 observations between `-2.157` and `2.830`, I would expect the horizontal axis shows values like between `-3` and `3`. What is actually measured on the horizon taxis?

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1234567)
k = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)
dens = sm.nonparametric.KDEUnivariate(k)
dens.fit()
plt.plot(dens.density)
```

[image]

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing

```
plt.plot(dens.density)
```

with

```
plt.plot(dens.support, dens.density)
```

gives the following result I expected.

[image]